# Getting an overview of user options (customizable variables) in Emacs

Tags: variables, emacs

I want to get an overview of user options (customizable variables) in Emacs, grouped by the packages they belong to.
I know that a command or hotkey for this exists, but google doesn't show up anything.

Comment: Does `M-x customize` do something like what you want?

Comment: @legoscia Looks good, thank you very much.

Comment: What exactly were you typing to Google search? `emacs customizable variable` shows me the answer immediately, as the first search hit.

Comment: @Drew Try 'emacs configure variable', and see how results diverge.

Answer (score 1):

GNU Emacs comes with an "Easy Customization Interface" that addresses exactly that. You can invoke it by typing <kbd>M-x customize</kbd>.

More information can be found in the [GNU Emacs Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html).